# SQL Server: converting UniqueIdentifier to string in a case statement

Tags: sql-server, guid, case

We have a log table that has a message column that sometimes has an exception stack trace. I have some criteria that determines if the message has this. We do not want to show these messages to the customer but instead have a message like:

> Internal Error Occured. Contact US
>   with reference code
>   xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

where xxx etc is a guid column in the table. I am writing stored proc like this:

```
declare @exceptionCriteria nvarchar(50)
select @exceptionCriteria = '%<enter criteria etc>%'

select LogDate,
       case
       when Message like @exceptionCriteria
       then 'Internal Error Occured. Reference Code: ' + str(RequestID)
       else Message
       end
  from UpdateQueue
```

`RequestID` is a Guid datatype in SQL Server and does not convert to string here. I've seen some code on how to convert a Guid to string, but it is multi-lined and I don't think it would work in a case statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 383, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

```
convert(nvarchar(36), RequestID)
```

Here's the link where I found this info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Alternatively, cast(RequestID as varchar(50))

Comment: What is the basic difference between cast() and convert() ?

Comment: I don't know why I'd pick `nvarchar`, much less `nvarchar(50)`. A unique identifier, when converted to a text value is treated in hex-dash-36.

Comment: i use it in my view and nicely worked and send them for my friends in SQL communities . GUID seems to confuse me ;)

Comment: As other answers says, you can condense this `cast(RequestID as char(36))`.

Comment: Shouldn't we be uppercase CONVERT

Comment: @P6345uk: That's a stylistic preference, and not a functional distinction; SQL Server is case insensitive when it comes to function names. I always use capital functions and keywords in my scripts, but it's not strictly required.

Answer (score 113):

It is possible to use the convert function here, but 36 characters are enough to hold the unique identifier value:

```
convert(nvarchar(36), requestID) as requestID
```

Edit: yes, as noted in the comments, char, or nchar, or any function that can properly manipulate ASCII character tables would do the trick. Then, my excuse is that I usually work in a multilingual/multialphabet environment, and the rule is to go for nvarchar, always. That's my no-brainer way of doing things, sorry. And, if one of these days, some database software starts to generate unique identifier with non-ASCII elements, I will be ready.

Comment: because length is fixed even varchar(36) is enough here

Comment: You say "fixed" and yet "varchar" in the same sentence ... how about `char(36)`? You might also use `nchar(36)`, but since a GUID doesn't contain unicode, it buys you nothing. Conversely, operations with `char` are generally faster than `varchar`.

Comment: Shouldn't we be uppercase CONVERT

Answer (score 74):

In my opinion, `uniqueidentifier` / GUID is neither a `varchar` nor an `nvarchar` but a `char(36)`. Therefore I use:

```
CAST(xyz AS char(36))
```

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `Str(RequestID)`, try `convert(varchar(38), RequestID)`

Comment: Did you mean `varchar(36)`? What accounts for the additional two characters when we're dealing with a GUID?

Comment: @JeremyCaney I edited my answer to show a better solution. This was a long time ago, but I think the column in the database had a 50 character length so this is why I had chosen that value.