# GUID + DataBind gives exception?

Tags: .net, data-binding, ado.net, guid

I have the following piece of code:

```
string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
string SqlString = "Select * From Memberships WHERE ApplicationId =  @username";
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString)) {
  using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlString, conn)) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@username";
    param.Value = UserName2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    conn.Open();
    using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      test.DataSource = reader;
      test.DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```

In this case the codes breaks on DataBind() with the following error: **Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.** This is caused because I'm using the ApplicationId in my query instead of the UserName. With the UserName all works fine.

I know that the GUID is causing the error, but I don't know why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is type of AplicationId in your db? If guid - your problem is comparing string parameter to guid.
 Cast one of them.

Something like 
convert(nvarchar(50), ApplicstionID)

See also
[SQL Server: converting UniqueIdentifier to string in a case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299918/sql-server-converting-uniqueidentifier-to-string-in-a-case-statement)

Comment: Yes, ApplicationID is a GUID. Can you help me how to cast the value for @username in my query?

Comment: That's it! Thanks for your help. It makes me wondering however, why was the exception being cast at the DataBind() method?

Comment: Because on my understanding, you really fetch the data only on binding.

Comment: I had a feeling that it would be something like that. Thanks for the help.