# Convert UniqueIdentifier to string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to convert `UniqueIdentifier` value to string value so I can read it.

I am working SSRS Report where I have set datasource for one report. Now, ReportServer has one table named as `DataSource` and it has one column named as `Link` and its type is `Link uniqueidentifier no  16`.

Is it possible to convert this value into `varchar()`?

I have tried below but it gives same value.

```
--To fetch Link
SELECT ds.Link,CAST(ds.Link AS VARCHAR(36)) str
FROM   DataSource    AS ds
       JOIN CATALOG  AS c ON  c.ItemID = ds.ItemID
WHERE  c.Name = 'ReportName'
```

It gives output like this,

[image]

***Note:*** I have already checked [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299918/sql-server-converting-uniqueidentifier-to-string-in-a-case-statement), but doesn't helped me.

Comment: Can you please add what's currently happening? Like error messages, current output. edit: I'm actually a bit unclear on what you're asking

Comment: no error message is there... pls check my updated question.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: And how you suppose to get this from GUID?

Comment: It is not possible to get something from GUID, it is just unique identifier and nothing more.

Comment: thanks for sharing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Guid/unique identifier generated by the system is (more or less) just a random string of characters. There's no encoded information you can extract, other than the type variant of the guid itself. That string is as readable as it's going to get.

Answer (score 0):

```
--To fetch Link
SELECT ds.Link, CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), ds.Link) as str
FROM   DataSource    AS ds
       JOIN CATALOG  AS c ON  c.ItemID = ds.ItemID
WHERE  c.Name = 'ReportName'
```

Comment: Gives same result.

Comment: Still it gives same value, I have one question though, this Data-source table has Link column - data type is uniqueidentifier. Can we read it as string or not?

Comment: It will just replace `-` with blank space what else it will do? I want to read the text of it. Like it should show `Reports/Datasourse/Name`